# MDX query from cube with filtre of part of the hierarchy

Tags: mdx

I have query:

```
select {[Measures].[Fact]} on columns,
    non empty(
         {[Divisions].[Division hierarchy].[LVL1]**.&[30672].Children.ALLMEMBERS**},
         {[Показатели].[Показатели].ALLMEMBERS}
    ) on rows FROM [PnL] where ([Date].[YM].[Month].&[201712])
```

How should I write it correctly?
I need all the branch of a part of the hierarchy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just .children without the allmembers should suffice, or use the function DESCENDANTS

Comment: Excelent, DESCENDANTS is that what I was finding